# Calling a URL in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, url

I would like to call a URL. Currently I am using a hidden iFrame to call this URL:

```
var data = {File: file,NAME: 'file.txt'};
<iframe src="requestFile?'+ $.param(data) + '" style="display: none;" ></iframe>
```

Now I would like to use AJAX to call the file. The file just has to be called.
I tried it with a GET request:

```
$.ajax({
    'url' : 'requestFile?'+ decodeURIComponent($.param(data)),
    'type' : 'GET',
    'success' : function(data) {
      if (data == "success") {
        alert('request sent!');
      }
    }
  });
```

Unfortunately this does not work. May there be a problem with the length of the URL? The file string is quite long. I do not get an error message.

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting any error in browser console?

Comment: `"requestFile?'+ $.param(data) + '" ` Obviously you  have a typo. Stackoverflow's syntax highlighting showed the bug! Hooray!

Comment: get requests do have character limits

Comment: That is not the error. The iFrame works. What is the character limit? So how can I simply call the url?

Comment: Post request works. Thank you.

Comment: please note you probably should call *encodeURIComponent()* and not *decodeURIComponent()*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use the `decodeURIComponent($.param(data)),` simply use the encode method .param as `$.param(data),`

decodeURIComponent does just what it says, decodes it and you want to use the encoded which $.param should do for you:  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/

NOTE: on that page they use the decodeURIComponent in an example so you can see the original decoded value/put it in a variable.

Reworked code (my assumption is that you DO return "success" string and not the actual file here?):

```
var myparam = var data = {File: file,NAME: 'file.txt'};
$.ajax({
    url: 'requestFile?' + $.param(myparam),
    type: 'GET'
}).done(function (data) {
    if (data == "success") {
        alert('request sent!');
    }
});
```

NOTE: You did not show how `file` was defined so I can only make the assumption that it is a JavaScript object somewhere.